# Multiply Very Large Numbers Accurately in Python

Tags: python, overflow, largenumber

I am trying to multiply very large floats by very large integers in Python and am noticing small inaccuracies.
For example:

```
a = 45310630.0
b = 1023473145

c = int(a * b)
print(c)
```

The answer I am getting is 
46374212988031352 but I know the answer should be 46374212988031350. When I change variable "a" to an integer, the multiplication is performed correctly. However, since "a" comes from a division (and might not be a whole number), I can't simply convert it to an integer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use [`fractions.Fraction`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html#fractions.Fraction) you can handle larger numbers accurately, at the cost of some efficiency:

```
from fractions import Fraction
a = Fraction(45310630.0)
b = Fraction(1023473145)

c = int(a * b)
print(c)
```

Output:

```
46374212988031350
```

Some timings:

```
In [2]: a = Fraction(45310630.0)
   ...: b = Fraction(1023473145)
   ...:

In [3]: %timeit int(a * b)
3.92 µs ± 21.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [4]: a = 45310630.0
   ...: b = 1023473145
   ...:

In [5]: %timeit int(a * b)
479 ns ± 13.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Comment: Note that to get an accurate result, you should not turn floats into fractions. The documentation warns about this and gives the example that the float 1.1 does not turn into the fraction 11/10 as expected.

Answer (score 3):

The reason that `c` is incorrect is [due to how Python and other languages perform floating point math](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/floatingpoint.html).

To circumvent this issue, you can use the `fraction` and `decimal` modules included in the standard library:

```py
>>> a = 45310630.0
>>> b = 1023473145
>>> expected = 46374212988031350
>>> int(a * b) == expected
False

>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> dec_a = Decimal.from_float(a)
>>> dec_b = Decimal.from_float(b)
>>> int(dec_a * dec_b) == expected
True

>>> from fraction import Fraction
>>> frac_a = Fraction.from_float(a)
>>> frac_b = Fraction.from_float(b)
>>> int(frac_a * frac_b) == expected
True
```