# How to accurately multiply big numbers in python

Tags: python-3.x

When I try to multiply `(1e+18)+1` and `(1e+18)`, I get `1e+36` as result which is not accurate. Whereas till `1e+11`, the result is accurate. I have also tried using `Decimal import`. But didn't work. Please help.

```
    from decimal import *
    getcontext().prec = 20

    #case 1
    p=(1e+11)+1
    q=1e+11
    r=p*q
    print(r)
    a=(r)/(q)
    print(a)
    if(a%q == 0):
        print ("YES")
    else:
        print("NO")

    #case 2  
    p=(1e+18)+1
    q=(1e+18)
    r=p*q
    print(r)
    a=(r)/(q)
    print(a)
    if(a%q == 0):
        print ("YES")
    else:
        print("NO")

    #case 3
    p=Decimal((1e+18)+1)
    q=Decimal(1e+18)
    r=p*q
    print(r)
    a=(r)/(q)
    print(a)
    if(a%q == 0):
        print ("YES")
    else:
        print("NO")
```

For case 1,the result is accurate. But for higher numbers, it is not working. In the example shown, it should print `NO` in `case2` and `case3`. i.e., when I use `1e+18`.

```
1.00000000001e+22
1.00000000001e+11
NO
1e+36
1e+18
YES
1.0000000000000000000E+36
1.0E+18
YES
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49684411/multiply-very-large-numbers-accurately-in-python

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But unfortunately, using Fraction also didn't work.

Comment: You should use integers, they have unlimited precision. Just be careful when creating them, for example use `int(1e18)+1 ` instead of `int(1e18+1)`

Comment: Yes, I have been using int(1e18+1). This small change int(1e18)+1 worked great.Thanks a lot. 
But my original code was something different from what I posted.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Thierry. Following is the link for original code. 
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57443552/division-of-1e1811e18-1e18-gives-1e18-in-python-3-6]