# Division of (1e18+1)(1e18)/(1e18) gives (1e18) in Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x

Below is the code & for inputs n=(1e18+1)*(1e18) and k=(1e18),the code should print "YES". But it prints "NO". This is because 'a' is getting a value of 1e18. But ideally, 'a' should be (1e18+1). Please help.

```
    for t in range(int(input())):
        n,k=input().split()
        n=int(n)
        k=int(k)
        if n>=k*k:
            a=n/k
            print("a is {}".format(a))
            if a%k==0: 
                print ("a%k is {} ans {}".format(a%k, "NO"))
            else: 
                print("a%k is {} ans {}".format(a%k, "YES"))
        else:
            print("YES")
```

INPUT:

```
3
1 1
30 5
1000000000000000001000000000000000000 1000000000000000000
```

OUTPUT:

```
a is 1.0
a%k is 0.0 and ans is NO
a is 6.0
a%k is 1.0 and ans is YES
a is 1e+18
a%k is 0.0 and ans is NO
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that you are using the 'normal' `/` division, that always produces a float. As floats have limited precision, 1e18+1 gets rounded to 1e18.

To solve the problem, use integer division `//`, that gives an integer.

By changing this line:

```
a = n // k
```

your code works, as shown in this sample output:

```
1
1000000000000000001000000000000000000 1000000000000000000
a is 1000000000000000001
a%k is 1 ans YES
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for detailed clarification. :)